# JSOM List Item Field Values

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

This should be an easy one but for some reason the answer is escaping me.

I am executing a query with joins that includes projected fields (fields from one of the joined lists) using JSOM.

Using server side code, the type of one of these field values is String and has a value in the format of "ID;#Value".

Using JSOM, how do I get the value of this field?  When I call the .toString() method on the field value, I get "[object Object]".  If I call typeof() on the field value, I get "string".  What am I missing?

*** UPDATE ***

The following appears in the query XML...

```
<ProjectedFields>
  <Field Name="LastName" Type="Lookup" List="Employees" ShowField="LAST_NAME" />
</ProjectedFields>
<ViewFields>
  <FieldRef Name="LastName" />
</ViewFields>
```

The following server-side code...

```
listItem["LastName"]
```

...will yield something like "1;#Smith".

The following client-side code...

```
listItem.get_item('LastName')
```

...will yield "[object Object]".  The type of this field value is indeed string (just as it was for the server-side code) as evidenced by the statement...

```
typeof(listItem.get_item('LastName')
```

...which yields "string".

Again, the question is how do I get the value "1;#Smith" using the client-side code?

Comment: Post relevant code.

Comment: Please see the update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field is a lookup field, wich is represented by a complex type [SP.FieldLookupValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246742.aspx) on the client side. You can retrieve the label and id as shown below:

```
var lastNameValue = item.get_item('LastName');
var lastNameLabel = lastNameValue.get_lookupValue();
var lastNameId = lastNameValue.get_lookupId();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  The fact that the type of the value was being reported as string was confusing.  After thinking about it a bit longer, I guess this is how the server-side code behaves (sort of).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the raw JSON being returned from the service call. Seeing what the raw data looks like should help you understand how it's represented in JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I marked the other answer as the solution as it took my issue to completion.  I couldn't even up-vote your answer as I do not have enough reputation points.